# ReactJS TypeError: _this3.state.Objects.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, google-maps, typeerror

I'm fetching some api data to google maps markers... I'm pretty newbie at ReactJS and last 2 days I'm getting the same error over and over again and I dont really know how to solve it. anyone can help me here? 
(also, its my 1st doing any kind of question here sorry if I'm doing something wrong)

> TypeError: _this3.state.Objects.map is not a function

```
class maps extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = { Objects: [] }
    }

    componentWillMount(){

        axios.get('https://api.ost.pt/traffic_events/?key=VMSBvXtmOixXVuaHqeyAxDEhQkbnJpXZBYjDufEu')
        .then( res => {

            console.log(res);
            this.setState({Objects: res})

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error); 
        });

    }

render(){

    const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>

    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={2}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.6333333, lng: -8.65 }}
    >
    {

  this.state.Objects.map(function(Objects, i) {
        return(
            <Marker position={{ lat: Objects.data.Objects.location.coodinates[i], lng: Objects.data.Objects.location.coodinates[i] }} />
        )
    })
    }

    {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: 40.6333333, lng: -8.65 }} />}
      {props.isMarkerShown && <Marker position={{ lat: 40.627467, lng: -8.64912 }} />}
    </GoogleMap>
  ))


}
```

}

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It's more UI-friendly to do the request in `componentDidMount` and showing some kind of loading UI while the request is running.

Comment: well, your `res` is not an array.. What are you getting in `console.log(res)` ??

Comment: `Res` may be object. Please check the console output. to map res shold be an array

Comment: I'm getting all API data on console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Objects.map` is not a function because `Objects` is not an array.

Within your `componentWillMount()` function: the `res` variable returned by the `axios.get()` request is an `object` containing extra info such as `headers` and `status text`.

The `data` you're actually after is within that `object`. See below for an example of how you might extract said data.

```
axios.get('https://api.ost.pt/traffic_events/?key=VMSBvXtmOixXVuaHqeyAxDEhQkbnJpXZBYjDufEu').then((response) => {

    const { Objects } = response.data // Extract Objects From Data.
    return this.setState({ Objects }) // Update Component State.

}).catch((error) => console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error))
```

See the [Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios) for further info.